# Why I get all dictionary keys when raw_input is empty

Tags: python, dictionary

When I just press enter for raw_input("select: ") question, I get all dictionary keys. Why I get it? and How can I avoid this problem?

```
dict={"tony":1,"jack":2,"apple":3}
search = raw_input("select: ")
number = 1
for i in dict.keys():
            if search in i:
                print number, i
                number +=1
```

Comment: Because `"" in "any string"` returns `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid:

```
if search in i and search != '':
```

Answer (score 0):

When you input *nothing*, `search` will be an empty string, and any string contains an empty string, that's why if `search == ''`, then `search in i == True` for all strings `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The question *why?* has an answer: It's because an empty string `''` is `in` each string.

I think you can try the full equality in your code:

```
 if search == i :
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the string is empty and if so, do not run the dictionary search. Python evaluates empty strings as `False`, which can be utilized here:

```
dict={"tony":1,"jack":2,"apple":3}
search = raw_input("select: ")
number = 1
if search:
   for i in dict.keys():
      if search in i:
         print number, i
         number +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is a substring of itself or any other string.

```
>>> ''.find('')
0
```

[Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)

> Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `"" in "abc"` will return `True`.

```
>>> '' in "tony"
True
>>> all('' in name for name in ["tony", "jack", "apple"])
True
>>> search = raw_input("select: ")
select: 
>>> print search

>>> type(search)
<class 'str'>
>>> len(search)
0
>>> '' in search # empty string
True
>>> search == ''
True
```

That is why your code is printing the dictionary keys even when the `search` has an empty string.

Instead of `if search in i:`, you may want to do `if search == i:`.